# Running PheWas on UK Biobank data: Error in svd(X): infinite or missing values in 'x' but no missing data

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I am using the Git Hub repo PHESANT to run a phenome-wide association study on clinical and brain imaging data from UK Biobank. The idea is that the phenome scan tests the association between a trait of interest (in my case, presence of cerebral small vessel disease) and an array of phenotypes by running a series of different types of regressions (linear, logistic, binomial, etc.) depending on the type of phenotype/variable.

I've been getting the error 'Error in svd(X): infinite or missing values in 'x''. My dependent variable is an integer variable denoting number of depression episodes, range is from -3 to 2052 where the vast majority of responses are coded with '-3' for 'Do not know'. My trait of interest/predictor variable is a continuous variable denoting volume of white matter hyperintensities. There are indeed missing values in it, but imputation does not make sense in my case and I should leave missing cases as they are due to the nature of my research question.

I have not been using R for a long time and would consider myself a beginner, but I think the error must be somewhere in the below lines (where the ordered logistic regression is specified):

```
`### BEGIN TRYCATCH
        tryCatch({
        confounders=thisdata[,3:numPreceedingCols, drop = FALSE]


        if (opt$standardise==TRUE) {
            geno = scale(geno)
                }

        fitB <- polr(phenoFactor ~ ., data=confounders, Hess=TRUE) 

        fit <- polr(phenoFactor ~ geno + ., data=confounders, Hess=TRUE)

        # only save results if model converged
        if (fit$convergence == 0 & fitB$convergence == 0) {

        ctable <- coef(summary(fit))
        sink()
        sink(resLogFile, append=TRUE)

        ct = coeftest(fit)

        # model p value compares model to baseline model
                lres = anova(fit, fitB)
        pvalue = pchisq(lres[2,"LR stat."], df=lres[2,"   Df"], lower.tail=FALSE)

        beta = ctable["geno", "Value"];

        if (opt$confidenceintervals == TRUE) {
            se = ctable["geno", "Std. Error"]
            lower = beta - 1.96*se;
                    upper = beta + 1.96*se;
                }
                else {
                        lower = NA
                        upper = NA
                }`
```

Particularly, these two lines:

```
`fitB <- polr(phenoFactor ~ ., data=confounders, Hess=TRUE) 

 fit <- polr(phenoFactor ~ geno + ., data=confounders, Hess=TRUE)`
```

Would anyone have ideas as to how to solve and what function to add where? I read other posts where it was suggested to scale the predictor. For me, the only reasonable option in light of my research question would be to categorize white matter hyperintensities into quantiles (as opposed to replacing missing values), but so far, I have only been using the original continuous UK Biobank variable.

I would appreciate any thoughts, many thanks in advance for your help and hope the post is written sufficiently well (as my first on Stackoverflow).

I replaced missing values in my dependent variable but seems like the error is thrown because of missing values in the predictor variable.